# How to apply this Excel formula to work with Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply the formula below (which is correct as far as I know) to conditional formatting, but it doesn't seem to be work properly. Any suggestions on how to fix this formula so that it works for conditional formatting would be greatly appreciated.

`OR(AND(NAs!$A2="x",NAs!$AD2<TODAY()),AND(NAs!$A2="x",NAs!$AD2=""))`

Comment: Did you forget to put a = sign before the formula? Also your question is not quite clear .. you need to explain the expected output from the formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=AND(NAs!$A2="x",NAs!$AD2<TODAY())
```

will work as a CF formula rule for at least a single cell. More than that and you need to disclose what it is you want.